# Need all Sales Reps on one Line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Below I have the following SQL Statement:

```
WITH SalesDetail as (
SELECT
PostAR.TxDate
 ,PostAR.AccountLink
 ,PostST.AccountLink AS StkLnk
 ,PostST.Quantity AS QtySold
 ,PostST.cAuditNumber
 ,(PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost) AS Profit
 ,(((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost)))/((((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit))))*100 AS GrossProfitPercent
 ,(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost) AS Cost
 ,(PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit) AS TotSales
 ,(((PostST.Credit-PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost))) / ((((PostST.Quantity*PostST.Cost)+(0.00000000000001))))*100 AS MarkUpPercent
 ,concat(StkItem.Code, ' - ' ,StkItem.Description_1) AS StkItemCode
 ,SalesRep.Code AS RepCode
 ,SalesRep.Name AS RepName
 ,Client.Account CustID
 ,Client.Name AS CustName

 ,CASE 
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) > 0 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 25  THEN 2
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 25 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 35  THEN 2.5
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 35 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 45  THEN 3
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 45 AND ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) < 55  THEN 3.5
         WHEN ((((PostST.Credit+PostST.Debit)-(PostST.Cost*PostST.Quantity))/((PostST.Cost+0.0000001)*PostST.Quantity))*100) >= 55 THEN 4
         ELSE 0
END AS CommPayablePercent

FROM PostAR 
 INNER JOIN PostST
ON PostST.cAuditNumber = PostAR.cAuditNumber
 INNER JOIN StkItem
ON StkItem.StockLink = PostST.AccountLink
 INNER JOIN SalesRep
ON SalesRep.idSalesRep = PostAR.RepID
 INNER JOIN Client
ON Client.DCLink = PostAR.AccountLink 
)
    SELECT  SalesDetail.RepName
    ,   (((SalesDetail.CommPayablePercent)/100)) * ((SalesDetail.TotSales))      As RepTotComm
    ,   SUM(SalesDetail.TotSales) AS TotalSales 

   FROM SalesDetail
   GROUP BY SalesDetail.RepName, SalesDetail.TotSales,       SalesDetail.CommPayablePercent
   ORDER BY SalesDetail.RepName
```

I then get the following result:

[image]

As you can see, it is multipling the TotSales by my already determained CASE formulala. That is fine. However, I do not want the reps all on a each line. I want just the rep name and then the total commission payable.

Eg:

GRAY MEIRING - $5000 - $6000

and not:

```
 GRAY MEIRING
 GRAY MEIRING 
 GRAY MEIRING etc etc...
```

Is the issue coming from my SUM function or perhaps my GROUP BY function?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY SalesDetail.RepName` only, to achieve It, you can add subquery, try something like that:

```
................
SELECT  RepName,
        SUM(RepTotComm),
        SUM(TotalSales)
FROM (
    SELECT  SalesDetail.RepName
    ,   (((SalesDetail.CommPayablePercent)/100)) * ((SalesDetail.TotSales))      As RepTotComm
    ,   SUM(SalesDetail.TotSales) AS TotalSales 

   FROM SalesDetail
   GROUP BY SalesDetail.RepName, SalesDetail.TotSales, SalesDetail.CommPayablePercent      
     ) x
GROUP BY RepName
ORDER BY RepName
```

Comment: Wonderful!! Worked. Thank you so much!